# Step references task InvokeRESTAPI at version 1.152.1 which is not valid for the given job target

Tags: azure, rest, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, pipeline

I have an Azure pipeline which needs to send a REST request to an endpoint. I am trying to use the built in task `InvokeRESTAPI@1` to do this, but it errors when running on Azure DevOps.

Script:

```
---
trigger:
  batch: true
  branches:
    include:
      - master
pr:
  - master

stages:
  - stage: Run_Tests
    jobs:
      - job: RA001
        pool: windows-server
        steps:
          - task: InvokeRESTAPI@1
            displayName: "Run Test"
            inputs:
              connectionType: 'connectedServiceName'
              serviceConnection: 'myconnection'
              method: 'PUT'
              headers: |
                {
                "AccessKey":"$(system.MyKey)"
                }
              urlSuffix: '/api/v3/schedules/uniquenumber/runNow'
              waitForCompletion: 'false'
```

Returns:

> Job RA001: Step references task 'InvokeRESTAPI' at version '1.152.1'
>   which is not valid for the given job target.

Answer (score 25):

The `InvokeRESTAPI@1` it's server job task (agentless job in the classic editor), not a regular task that can run on an agent.

You need to put it in server job in this way:

```
pool: server
```

More info you can find [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#server-jobs).